# Display enums of selected item in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf

When a user selects an item from a list on my WPF page, I'm trying to show that item's list of enums in another DataGrid:

```
<DataGrid Grid.Row="1" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" 
    HeadersVisibility="Column"
    ItemsSource="{Binding SelectedAdGroupWithRoles.PrestoRoles}"
    SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedPrestoRole}">                    
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PrestoRole}" Header="Role" Width="*"/>
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

PrestoRole is an enum.

I'm not sure how to set that final binding:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding PrestoRole}" Header="Role" Width="*"/>
```

I've tried a few things, but the PrestoRole name won't display. How can I get it to display?

On a completely separate form, I list every member of the PrestoRole enum in a listbox:

```
<ListBox Grid.Row="0" ItemsSource="{Binding Roles}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedRole}" Height="auto">
```

The Roles property, on the view model, looks like this:

```
public List<PrestoRole> Roles
```

The enum member displays just fine there. I just can't get it to show in the DataGrid.

Comment: It seems that your question has already been answered in this topic: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207607/how-to-display-enum-type-in-datagridtextcolumn

Comment: That link is to create a converter. I'm hoping that I don't have to do that.

Comment: Maybe this can help you: [link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/c7a5c9ea-1967-425e-817d-723e22234f41/how-to-display-enum-type-in-wpf-datagrid-column)
Or this: [link](http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/900106-how-add-datagridcomboboxcolumn-datagrid-wpf)

Comment: Thanks, @Steven, but Adi's answer solved my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding}" Header="Role" Width="*"/>
```

When you define a column, the column's `DataContext` is set to the current item for each row, so all you need to do is bind to it.

Comment: Perfect. Simple and clean. Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!